# Conflict with dependency 'com.squareup.okio: okio'

Tags: java, android-studio, dependencies, conflict

While running my code with Android Studio, it generates this error:

> Warning: Conflict with dependency 'com.squareup.okio: okio'. Resolved versions for app (1.11.0) and test app (1.6.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Answer (score 5):

Perhap you are adding this library for expresso UI testing with retrofit2

> androidTestCompile
>   'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'

Here is what my solution look like:

```
 androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0',{
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio', module: 'okio'
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
```

It will keep gradle from downloading conflicting dependencies.

This problem happens because you added with **androidTestCompile** instead of normal **compile**. If you replace the former by the later, the error goes away. I think the reason is that gradle will selects the highest dependency's version.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the mentioned website (http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict) you can read the different options you have to solve this problem.

If you cannot narrow the conflicting libraries run first the following command, to see which versions are conflicting:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

There are two possible solutions to this problem:

1.- Change the libraries versions, so they do not conflict anymore

2.- Use [Gradle Conflict Resolution Mechanism](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) to specify the version you want to resolve to.

Comment: I'm not even using **okio** directly, and getting this issue.